# Center Div when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

How can I better center the div elements (which are off screen on the right)? Trying to make popups appear from the right side to the center over the buttons but they are slightly off centered. I set the position of each popup box to absolute positioning and I am using javascript to change the top and left values. I plan on having the popup to slide back to its original position after 8 seconds.

```js
loadEventListeners();

function loadEventListeners() {
    cancelButton.addEventListener('click', moveCancelPopUp);
    acceptButton.addEventListener('click', moveAcceptPopUp);
}

function moveCancelPopUp() {
    cancelPopUp.style.position = 'absolute';
    cancelPopUp.style.top = '50%';
    cancelPopUp.style.left = '50%';
}

function moveAcceptPopUp() {
    acceptPopUp.style.position = 'absolute';
    acceptPopUp.style.top = '50%';
    acceptPopUp.style.left = '50%';
}
```

```css
.accept-popup-box,
.cancel-popup-box {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

.cancel-popup-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: -100%;
}

.accept-popup-box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
        <button class="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
        <button class="accept-btn">Accept</button>
        <div class="cancel-popup-box">
                <div class="cancel-popup-content">
                    <p>Come Back Soon.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accept-popup-box">
                <div class="accept-popup-content">
                    <p>Thank You!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="challenge2.js"></script>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your snippet has errors. "Uncaught ReferenceError: cancelButton is not defined". If `cancelButton` is supposed to reference `cancel-btn` you'll want to use a selector to assign it first perhaps?

Comment: Sorry I didnt incude the variables in the snippet: const cancelButton = document.querySelector('.cancel-btn');
const acceptButton = document.querySelector('.accept-btn');
const cancelPopUp = document.querySelector('.cancel-popup-box');
const acceptPopUp = document.querySelector('.accept-popup-box');

Comment: Ah, I thought that might be the case. Let me poke around your code and see if I can find anything...